# Is there a way to find out if an object has been dispose() or not?

Tags: vb.net, object, try-catch, dispose, disposable

I have the following object that later in my code I want to dispose() IF it exists. Is there a way to find if it exists?

```
Public objExcel As Excel.Application
```

The best I could come up with is to put the disposal into a try...catch block like this:

```
Try
   objExcel.dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
   'do nothing
End Try
```

Does anyone have a more elegant, less kludgy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dispose of an Excel object completely you must you the marshal class. `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`. You also need to release all the excel objects in reverse order - Worksheet, workbook, excel object. If you don't you can see the Excel process in task manager.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obgExcel)
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if object is initialized, then you can safely dispose it.

```
If objExcel isnot nothing then objExcel.dispose()
```

Comment: This will cause problems and throw ObjectDisposed Exceptions. You would need to use objExcel = Nothing after you have disposed of it, before checking with IsNot Nothing.